# Spring + MongoDB performance drops by half after few thousand of documents

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongotemplate

Have a service that starting from a clean database is able to insert documents at a rate of 70/second, after a few thousands i see the performance drop by half.

Documents follow a structure similar to http://schema.org/Product and their http://schema.org/Offer

I'm using Spring + MongoTempate and MongoDB 3.4 with a single index on each offer own id and seller id:

```
    db.getCollection('ProductFullDetails').createIndex({'offers.offers.seller.sellerId': 1, 'offers.offers.sellerProductId': 1});
```

Comment: What is the collection and queries like? What indices do you have on your collection?

Comment: @hyades, the post as been modified.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the lack of an index.

Though this might sound obvious, in reality it took a careful look in order to find the optimal set of indexes to use as too much was also the cause for issues.

Used both the mongostat and the [Mongo Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass) tools for this task. Among several others, the most amazing functionality is the Compass "slowest operations" found under the database performance analytics.